# Outlook AddIn - Perform Actions on Selected Emails

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've done some research on creating Outlook Add-Ins and have come to the conclusion that the only functionality available is the ability to add menu items or buttons when viewing a single email or appointment. I'm basing this conclusion on the [Add-In Command Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook). When I say Outlook Add-In I don't mean a VSTO or COM Add-In, but rather the newer functionality that uses Office JS and deploys an XML manifest and web code.

What I would like to do is be able to select multiple emails and have a button or menu that will do some action. Is this possible? Is the only alternative to create a client side COM Add-In?